# routing causes Null Entry

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, paypal

On my project, the user can select to pay via paypal, this then takes them to the paypal site. After finishing the user then returns to my site and is taken directly to the "**Choose Address**" page. At this point I get the error;

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Address' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult CheckoutPaypal(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection, System.String, Int32)' in 'T_shirt_Company_v3.Controllers.CheckoutController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

in my webconfig is the return address;

```
<add key="return" value="http://localhost:57564/Checkout/CheckoutPayPal" />
```

Here is my controller for the "**Choose Address**"

```
 public ActionResult CheckoutPaypal()
        {
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
            if (!cart.GetCartItems().Any())
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Store");

            ViewBag.standard = cart.GetTotal();
            ViewBag.fclass = cart.GetTotal() + 5;
            ViewBag.fourty = cart.GetTotal() + 10;


            return View();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the address and payment from the user
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="values">address, payment, contact details</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CheckoutPaypal(FormCollection values, string id, int Address)
        {

            var order = new Order();
            TryUpdateModel(order);


            var deliveryAddress = storeDB.deliveryAddresses.Where(x => x.AdressId == Address).FirstOrDefault();


            order.Address = deliveryAddress.Address;
            order.City = deliveryAddress.City;
            order.Country = deliveryAddress.Country;
            order.PostalCode = deliveryAddress.PostalCode;
            order.FirstName = deliveryAddress.FirstName;
            order.LastName = deliveryAddress.LastName;
            order.Phone = deliveryAddress.Phone;
            order.Email = User.Identity.GetUserName();
            order.EmailConfirm = User.Identity.GetUserName();
            order.PaymentTransactionId = "Paid with paypal";
            //sets date and username
            order.Username = User.Identity.Name;
            order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;


            //Order gets saved
            storeDB.Orders.Add(order);
            storeDB.SaveChanges();


            //Order gets processed
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
            cart.CreateOrder(order);

            //Save again, total not saving properly until now
            storeDB.SaveChanges();


            var postageno = order.PostageList.ToString();
            //adds the postage cost onto the total and updates the database
            if (postageno == "FirstClass")
            {
                decimal addpostage = 5;
                order.Total = order.Total + addpostage;
                storeDB.SaveChanges();
            }
            else if (postageno == "TwentyFourHour")
            {
                decimal addpostage = 10;
                order.Total = order.Total + addpostage;
                storeDB.SaveChanges();
            }


            //Used to change quantity after order made and saved
            using (TshirtStoreDB db = new TshirtStoreDB())
            {
                var details = db.OrderDetails.Where(od => od.OrderId == order.OrderId);

                foreach (var od in details)
                {
                    Product prod = (from p in db.Products where p.ProductId == od.ProductId select p).Single();

                    prod.Quantity -= od.Quantity;
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Complete",
                        new { id = order.OrderId });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way to counter this was to redirect to a blank page, then immediately redirect back to the checkout page, this removed the error and functions well